# ParallelTable should distribute dedicated evaluation range to different kernels

Tags: parallelization, kernel, kernel-startup

I have 4 kernels and would like that in `ParallelTable`:

```
kernel 1 takes i from   1 to  250
kernel 2 takes i from 251 to  500
kernel 3 takes i from 501 to  755
kernel 4 takes i from 756 to 1000
```

How can I do that as example for the lower code?

```
ParallelTable[

 x = i^2;
 Print[x],

 {i, 1, 1000}

 ]
```

Comment: `ParallelTable` doesn't seem to have that, maybe something like `ParallelEvaluate[
  Table[{$KernelID, 
    n}, {n, ($KernelID - 1) 250 + 1, $KernelID 250}]]~Flatten~1`

Comment: How would the code look like when I want to read images from a `List` `imageNamesList` e.g. `ParallelTable[ Import[ imageNamesList[[i]] ],  {i, 1, 1000} ]`

Comment: Like this, right?  `ParallelEvaluate[
  Table[Import[
    imageList[[n]]], {n, ($KernelID - 1) 250 + 
     1, $KernelID 250}]]~Flatten~1`

Comment: I get the following errors: `(kernel 1) Part::partd: Part specification imageNamesList[[1]] is longer than depth of object. (kernel 2) Part::partd: Part specification imageNamesList[[251]] is longer than depth of object.` and so on ?

Comment: Then you have to set imageNamesList as a shared variable, right?  `SetSharedVariable[imageNamesList]`

Comment: @Jason B Thank you ... this is the solution

Comment: No ... thank you for the hint

Comment: @mrz If Jason does not enter an answer himself, perhaps you could consider writing an answer to your own question to preserve his contribution for others. 1) Questions that show up answered are much more attractive down the line to people looking for solutions to their own problems. 2) As you know, self-answering is encouraged here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of Jason B.

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Table[
    {$KernelID, i};
    x = i^2;
    Print["$KernelID = ", $KernelID, ", i = ", 
     i ", x = \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(2\)]\) = ", x],
    {i, ($KernelID - 1) 250 + 1, $KernelID 250}
    ];
  ];
```

Output is correct:
(I only do not understand why for i=1 no output is shown?)

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: "I only do not understand why for i=1 no output is shown" - when you are building statements like this to print, combining strings and numbers, the best way to do it is by converting everything to a string and using `StringJoin` to combine them.   `Print["$KernelID = " <> IntegerString[$KernelID] <> ", i = " <> 
  IntegerString[i] <> 
  ", x = \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(2\)]\) = " <> IntegerString[x]]`

Comment: @Jason B: can you overtake my written solution (which is yours), so I can accept it as solved?

Comment: no worries, you should accept this as is  :-)

Comment: It is not possible to vote for my own answer ...

Comment: I just meant that you should accept it, with the green check mark, since it is the solution to the problem. There isn't a way to transfer the ownership of a post, and it really is not a big deal for the attribution.  You could make the answer a community wiki I think, but I'm not familiar with how to do that.  Cheers